# Discord.js how can bot ping when someone with a specific role leave

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a bot and I want to add a feature to my bot. ping a specific room when people with a custom role leave the server. So, for example, we'll know when people with the "partner" role come out.
I wanna write code in index.js.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be aware this is not a code-writing service. We can help solve specific and technical problems, not requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what error you face.

Comment: Post your current work so we can help you what do you wanted to do

Answer (score 1):

Lemme tell you this isn't much related to discordjs itself, but the way discord client works. You should not probably ping a user who has left the server, as uncached users on mobile or any user may show as invalid user. Therefore you should log username#discriminator, or actually tag and then user id incase you want to keep the record of their IDs for future ping, etc.

Edit after you commented:
There's `guildMemberRemove` event for your client bot.
Info: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberRemove

It emits `member` object, and you can get that user's name, etc from that. You can make the bot dm you, or send a message in a specific channel, and ping you.

**Important Notice:** keep your bot private, in your server only, or else, add a if condition to check whether the member who left was from your specific server or not, or else the bot may log that user even if he didn't leave your own server.

Answer (score 0):

In `guildMemberRemove` event you can specify the alert message.
Check member has a role or not then send your message in right situation.